# Store values from multiple select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable with the number of select items, this number depends on some API, and I want to store the selection of each question into localstorage so each time the page reloads the selection stays remained, I don't know how to do it.

```
 { Object.entries(this.state.liste).map( ([ke,values]) => {
                          let question=ke
 return (                            
 <div  name = "question"  >
  <h6 className="left">{ke}</h6>     
  < select className="right"  key={values} name = "answer to each question"  onChange={(event) => 
   this.handleChangeaa(question,event)} >
   <option value={this.state.selected} selected disabled hidden onChange={(value)=> 
    console.log(value)}>  Not answered </option> 

    {Object.values(values).map(key=>{ 
     return (<option  key={key.id} id={key}>{key}</option>) })}
   </select>
   </div>
    ) })}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In localStorage, you can only set a value as a string. You simply have to insert in the localStorage some pairs of key/values for each questions that have a selected option. In this case, the key will be the `id` of your question and the value the `value` of your selected option.

In your `handleChangeaa` callBack, you will have something like this :

```
handleChangeaa(question, event) {
    // Check before if the localStorage is available
    localStorage.setItem(question.id, event.target.value);
}
```

Then when your form component will be instantiated, you will simply have to retrieve this information from your localeStorage with the `localStorage.getItem` function :

```
componentDidMount() {
   // Check if localStorage is available
   const stateListCpy = {...this.state.liste}
   ["question1", "question2"].forEach((questionId) => {
       const questionValue = localStorage.getItem(questionId);

       if (questionValue) {
           const questionIndex = stateListCpy.findIndex((questionBlock) => questionBlock.ke === questionId )
           if (questionIndex !== -1) {
               stateListCpy[questionIndex].values = questionValue;
           }
       }
   })
   this.setState({
       liste = stateListCpy;
   })
}
```

And with that you will have your selects initialized with the right values from your localStorage.

Good luck !